# Whoops! There was an error. NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I can see that Laravel is not able to get resources when the resource name includes a plus sign (+)

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

```
GET http://localhost:8000/vendor/store/store+json2.min.js 404 (Not Found)

GET http://localhost:8000/vendor/animo/animate+animo.css 404 (Not Found)

REQUEST_URI /vendor/store/store+json2.min.js
REQUEST_METHOD  GET
SCRIPT_NAME /vendor/store/store json2.min.js

REQUEST_URI /vendor/animo/animate+animo.css
REQUEST_METHOD  GET
SCRIPT_NAME /vendor/animo/animate animo.css
```

I can solve that by changing the filename with removing the plus sign. But is there any way to do that without changing filename?

I am using Laravel 4.*

Here is the contents in the route file:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

// Confide routes
Route::get('users/create', 'UsersController@create');
Route::get('users/create/{plan}', 'UsersController@create');
Route::post('users', 'UsersController@store');
Route::get('users/login', 'UsersController@login');
Route::post('users/login', 'UsersController@doLogin');
Route::get('users/confirm/{code}', 'UsersController@confirm');
Route::get('users/forgot_password', 'UsersController@forgotPassword');
Route::post('users/forgot_password', 'UsersController@doForgotPassword');
Route::get('users/reset_password/{token}', 'UsersController@resetPassword');
Route::post('users/reset_password', 'UsersController@doResetPassword');
Route::get('users/logout', 'UsersController@logout');

Route::resource('categories', 'CategoriesController');
Route::resource('forms', 'FormsController');
Route::resource('submissions', 'SubmissionsController');
```

Comment: Can we see your route(s)?

Comment: @lukasgeiter please check again that I have updated with the routes.php contents

Comment: Wait, are you trying to access files with your browser that are inside the vendor directory??

Comment: yes in public folder: myproject/public/vendor/

Comment: Does your `.htaccess` file in the public directory look [like this](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess)? (Especially the `RewriteCond` part)

Comment: Yes its unchanged. Same with that one.

Comment: Hmmm. Does it work if you use `%2B` instead of `+`?

Comment: Thats great! its working nicely after replacing `+` with `%2B`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem is that for some reason the two rewrite conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Are not working correctly with your requests. They should prevent that file requests are proxied off to Laravel. It also seems to be environment related. (On my local server it worked perfectly fine)

A workaround that apparently works is replacing `+` with the URL encoded value `%2B`.
Or just use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php):

```
urlencode('http://localhost:8000/vendor/store/store+json2.min.js')
```